# Respuesta json en c#

Tags: php, c#, json

Json response con Postman:

```
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "correo": "x@e.com",
        "clave": "123456",
        "numero": "+1 5412-2154"
    }
]
```

Buton de login:

```
try
            {

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string postData = "correo='" + txtuser.Text + "' and clave='" + txtpassword.Text + "'";
                byte[] DataBindings = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/usuario_login.php");

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = DataBindings.Length;

                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(DataBindings, 0, DataBindings.Length);
                stream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                String Mensaje = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (Mensaje.Equals("null"))
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Al parecer los datos no coinciden";
                    btnlogin.Text = "Iniciar Sesión";
                }
                else
                {
                    voiceUrl admin = new voiceUrl(Mensaje);
                    this.Hide();
                    admin.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
                sr.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);

            }
```

Error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Archivo php de consulta:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
include('conexion.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
$correo= $_POST['correo'];
$clave= $_POST['clave'];  
$result  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' and clave='$clave'") or mysqli_error($con);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $arr[] = $row;
}

$json = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json;
}
```

Alguien sabe que es lo que esta pasando?

Comment: ¿Mismo dominio o son dominios diferentes?

Comment: mismo dominio, estoy ejecutando ese archivo php desde c# pero no puedo recoger la informacion.

Comment: Estás enviando en tu cadena `string postData = "correo='" + txtuser.Text + "' and clave='" + txtpassword.Text + "'";`. Prueba a separar los campos con `&` en lugar de `and`: `string postData = "correo=" + txtuser.Text + "&clave=" + txtpassword.Text;`

Comment: el Fatal Error dice que tu error esta en que $result es nulo no? estas ejecutando fech_assoc sobre un objeto nulo, revisa si la consulta en el archivo php te esta devolviendo algo

Answer (score 0):

100% seguro que la variable result es un booleano.

tienes un operador lógico en la linea donde haces la consulta:

```
$result  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' and clave='$clave'") or mysqli_error($con);
```

Este "or" vuelve el resultado un booleano dependiendo si tienes error (true) o si tienes resultados.

Haz un var_dump() al result y veras que tipo de dato es.